# Starting Pro-Engineer in a Folder with RMB menu

Tags: windows-7, command-line, windows-registry

The issue in link below sounds like it may be related to a problem I am having getting Pro-Engineer to start in the Folder I RMB on. If I create a Folder within the Folder I want Pro-E to start in and RMB on it Pro-E starts in the parent Folder (this is a work around). If I RMB on the Folder I want Pro-E to start in (a Mapped Network Drive) then it starts in C:\Windows\system32.
This worked correctly in Windows XP and Vista but not in Windows 7.

[Why doesn't "Open console here" open cmd on the correct drive if not used on the C-Drive?](https://superuser.com/questions/251558/why-doesnt-open-console-here-open-cmd-on-the-correct-drive-if-not-used-on-the)

Comment: What is the code that is being used in the context menu?

Comment: "C:\Program Files\proeWildfire 5.0\bin\proe.exe" "-g:opengl" %1