# Windows open command window here doesn't load env. variables

Tags: windows, command-line, environment-variables

In windows if I right click and select "Open command window here" in a particular folder it works exactly the same way as "Open terminal here" works in Linux.

It was working find until I installed a few software that disturbed the environment variables. A few environment variables are not available anymore. For example, when a command window is opened from the start menu and "Perl" command is executed, it works, but in the previous case I get the following error

> 'perl' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
>   program or batch file.

Further, PATH env. variable values are different for both when `echo %path%` is run.

After reading [this](https://superuser.com/a/251926/252835) answer I found out that I already have the suggested registery key values which are as following

> cmd.exe /s /k pushd "%V"

Any suggestions?

Comment: Does anyone have any suggestion??

Answer (score 1):

When environment variables are added or changed, currently open Command windows must be closed and re-opened to see the changes. I have found that in order to make the "Open command window here" option see the changes I must also close and re-open Windows Explorer.

Comment: Typical, but restarting explorer does work :)